# sync.Map or channels when using a goroutines

Tags: multithreading, dictionary, go, goroutine

I'm writing program that parses a lot of files looking for "interesting" lines. Then it's checking if these lines were seen before. Each file is parsed using separate goroutine.
I'm wondering which approach is better:

1. Use sync.Map or something similar
2. Use channels and separate goroutine which should be responsible only for uniqueness check (probably using standard map). It would receive request and respond with something simple like "Not unique" or "Unique (and added)"

Is any of these solutions more popular or maybe both are wrong?

Comment: If parsing files, likely the bottleneck will be your IO read speed anyway, so it won't matter. Do what's simplest / cleanest for you.

Comment: You need to describe your program better. What is the output at the end, what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have workers which can access a global map for unique checking, you can use a `sync.RWMutex` to be sure that the map is protected, like:

```
var (
  mutex sync.RWMutex = sync.RWMutex{}
  alreadySeen map[string]struct{} = make(map[string]struct{})
)

func Work() {
  for {
    Processing lines here...
    //Checking 
    mutex.RLock() //Lock for reading only
    if _, found := alreadySeen[line]; !found {
       mutex.RUnLock()
       mutex.Lock()
       alreadySeen[line] = struct{}{}
       mutex.UnLock()
    } else {
       mutex.RUnLock()
    }
  }
}
```

Another approach is to use a concurrent safe map to skip the whole mutexing, for example this package: https://github.com/cornelk/hashmap